# Unable to understand how to merge Rows in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm writing a program where I need to merge rows in Excel sheet. Currently, I'm able to merge the starting rows, but when coming to the end, I'm unable to know where it is going wrong. Below is my code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class RowsMerge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(
                new File("C:\\D\\Sheets\\Sample Sheets\\dummy.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fin);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int row = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        String currentLawName, currentCountry, currentAssociate, previousLawName, previousCountry, previousAssociate;
        String currentPages, previousPages;
        int startIndex = 1, finalIndex = 0, tempNum = 0;
        System.out.println(row);
        for (int i = 2; i < (row - 1); i++) {
            currentAssociate = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString();
            currentLawName = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).toString();
            currentCountry = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2).toString();
            currentPages = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3).toString();

            previousAssociate = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(0).toString();
            previousLawName = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(1).toString();
            previousCountry = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(2).toString();
            previousPages = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(3).toString();

            if (currentAssociate.equals(previousAssociate) && currentCountry.equals(previousCountry)
                    && currentLawName.equals(previousLawName) && currentPages.equals(previousPages)) {
                finalIndex += 1;
            } else {
                sendRangeToMergeCells(startIndex, finalIndex, sheet);
                startIndex = i;
                finalIndex = 0;

            }

        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\D\\Sheets\\Sample Sheets\\dummy.xls");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }

    private static void sendRangeToMergeCells(int startIndex, int finalIndex, HSSFSheet sheet) {
        System.out.println(startIndex + "\t" + (startIndex + finalIndex));
        CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress
                .valueOf("D" + (startIndex + 1) + ":D" + ((startIndex + finalIndex) + 1));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
    }

}
```

Below is my Excel Sheet

**SourceExcel:**

[image]

**Current output:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: isn't it because your're ending the for loop in i < row-1 instead of i < row?

Comment: Hi @Leo Still the result is same

Comment: don't you have to set finalIndex to i instead of 0 in the for loop?

Comment: @Leo You mean both startIndex and finalIndex has to be `i`?

Comment: Hey Sorry this didn't work..:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112753/discussion-between-rakesh-and-leo).

Comment: @Leo, this is working if there is a blank row at the bottom. i.e. blankRow > (row+2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your merge logic is fine, it is your break logic (the logic which determines when to merge the rows) that is missing a bit.

If the last row in your spreadsheet matches the previous row, no merge will be performed because execution will follow the first branch of `if (currentAssociate.equals(previousAssociate) && ...` and the loop ends. You have to test for and execute the merge logic if necessary one last time after the `for` loop completes.

Add the following after your `for` loop:

```
if (finalIndex > 0) {
    sendRangeToMergeCells(startIndex, finalIndex, sheet);
}
```

this will merge the last rows if necessary.